# Instalar Site Laravel em Servidor Windows

Tags: laravel, windows, hospedagem

Eu nunca tive essa experiência de colocar um site no ar usando o Windows Server 2012 na Locaweb.

Coloquei o site numa pasta chamada 'sitenovo'.
E quando mando rodar o site faz assim:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>   C:\PHP_5.5\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Mas agora não está aparecendo um erro que antes estava. Dizia que não tinha permissão de abrir a pasta storage e um arquivo de log do Laravel.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "E:\home\jslhidraulica\Web\sitenovo\storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in E:\home\jslhidraulica\Web\sitenovo\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler.php:97

Mas todas as pastas estão com CHMOD 777. Já verifiquei.

Todos os requirementos do Laravel 5.2 estão habilitados no PHP do Windows.
Estou usando a versão PHP 5.5.13.

E todos os módulos requisitados estão habilitados.

Acredito que tenha a ver com alguma configuração que tem no .htaccess. Mas que eu saiba Windows não lê .htaccess e sim web.config.

Mas eu não sei configurar URL amigável no web.config.

Comment: Laravel 5.2 só corre em php >= 5.5.9 https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#server-requirements

Comment: 5.5.9, não é isso ?

Comment: Opps, claro desculpe o lapso

Comment: Mas viu... eu estou pesquisando na NET. Carregou o site agora, mas sem  imagens sem nada...

Comment: Veja na consola o porquê? Pode ser um erro 403, provavelmente permissões

Comment: Não apareceu nada no console.

Comment: A sério? E se fizer inspecionar elemento em cima de uma imagem que supostamente deveria aparecer? aparece o cominho para ela? Consegue também ver isso se em vez de ir a consola for a network e fizer refresh da página, aí vê todas as requisições e respostas feitas

Comment: Aparece isso no Console. Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:

Comment: Mas agora que eu vi. Ele não carrega o site novo que eu fiz, ele carrega o atual tudo errado sem CSS. É o meu WebConfig que está errado. Não sei mexer nele

Comment: Meu caro, nesse caso as minhas competências ficam por aqui lol. Não sei como ajuda-lo a partir daqui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para hospedar o Laravel no Windows deve-se configurar o arquivo `web.config` nos mesmos conformes do `.htaccess` para Servidor Linux.

Para isso pode-se usar uma ferramenta de conversão de `.htaccess` para `web.config` que o **IIS (Internet Information Service)**.

E depois tem que instalar um complemento chamado **IIS Remote Manager**, que é um Gerenciador de sites em Servidor Windows, como se fosse um cPanel.

[Passo a Passo - IIS Remote Manager Locaweb](https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/IIS_Remote_Manager)

[Download IIS Remote Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41177)

Lá dentro tem um módulo de conversão fácil de usar. Cola o código do `.htaccess` que o Laravel gera dentro da pasta **public** no bloco de cima e clica no botão para converter.

Mas para facilitar tudo isso vou colocar abaixo o código do `.htaccess` convertido para `web.config`.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <!--# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...-->
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <!--# Handle Front Controller...-->
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Me ajudou muito! Me salvou!